# Wicket DropDown (<select>) like form component that can show images

Tags: wicket

I'm looking for drop down component that can show images and will hopefully work on most browsers.

There are several extension libraries for wicket, such as wicketstuff-dojo and wiquery. Do any of these have such a component and how well does it integrate into wicket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no ready-to-use wicket extension that does exactly what you want.

I'd recommend using [wiquery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/) and writing a custom plugin based on something like [Image Dropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. Any ideas if wiquery developer like to adopt contributed plugins?